# Не найден пакет snapd Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

я хотел установить snap вводя команду:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

но мне выдает ошибку "E: Невозможно найти пакет snapd"

весь код

```
$ sudo apt-get install snapd
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет snapd
```

Comment: `apt-get update` делали перед попыткой?

Comment: @EOF Да, делал.

Comment: А что говорит `apt-cache show snapd`?

Comment: @EOF $ apt-cache show snapd
N: Невозможно найти пакет snapd
E: Не найдено ни одного пакета

Comment: У Вас ОС установлена, или в live режиме?

Comment: @EOF да, в live режиме

Comment: [Installing snap from a live Kali Linux environment is not currently supported.](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-kali)